# How to properly cleanup after google mock objects when calling exit(0)?

Tags: c++, googlemock, code-cleanup

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/program-termination?view=msvc-170#exit-function, *"Issuing a return statement from the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the return value as its argument."*.

Yet this proves to be wrong as the following example demonstrates:

main.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
 
#include "MyClass.h"  // defines a class named `MyClass`
#include "mock_test.h"
 
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::Return;
 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Mock_MyClass mock_;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_, foo(_))
        .WillRepeatedly(Return(0));
 
    exit(0);
}
```

mock_test.h

```
class Mock_MyClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, foo, (string& _), (override));
};
```

Assume that `MyClass` defines a virtual destructor and a method `virtual int foo(string &)` (yet the full content of `MyClass` is not relevant).

Upon running the program resulting from the preceding source code, I systematically get the following error:

**ERROR: this mock object should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0000000001100EF0.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.**

However, if `exit(0)` is replaced with `return 0`, I no longer get this error.

Hence it seems that calling `exit(0)` bypasses some cleanup process that happens when `return 0` is used.

How can one, using `exit(0)`, have the program cleanup after google mock objects  in the same way that using `return 0` would? That would enable one to terminate the program execution from a subfunction by calling `exit(0)` while ensuring to not get the above-mentioned error.

(I compiled for Linux, armv7, with -std=c++17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an information specific to MSVC compiler only. cppreference on [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) says:

> Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called.

For comparison, a moment later returning from `main` is mentioned:

> Returning from the main function, either by a return statement or by reaching the end of the function performs the normal function termination (calls the destructors of the variables with automatic storage durations) and then executes std::exit, passing the argument of the return statement (or ​0​ if implicit return was used) as exit_code.

That is consistent with C++ standard [support.start.term](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.start.term#9)

> [...]  (Objects with automatic storage duration are not destroyed as a result of calling `exit()`.)

So the only standard way to call those destructors is to

- change object storage duration to static one (`thread_local` may work, I'm not sure) or
- to use `return` instead of `std::exit` or
- ensure destruction before `std::exit` call (e.g. by introducing another scope for the mock objects).